# json multiple json data parsing in java

Tags: java, json

I have a json input like this

```
[ {
    "Company":"BEG",
    "Account":"1001",
    "Deptid":"",
    "Location":"",
    "Transaction Date":"2014-07-15",
    "Description":"Invoice",
    "Debit":0.0,
    "Credit":13.46,
    "Invoice Nbr":"1682"
    },
    {
    "Company":"BEG2",
    "Account":"1002",
    "Deptid":"23",
    "Location":"NY",
    "Transaction Date":"2014-07-15",
    "Description":"Invoice",
    "Debit":0.0,
    "Credit":13.45,
    "Invoice Nbr":"1682432"
    },
    ....
    ....
    },
    {
    "Company":"BEG99",
    "Account":"1099",
    "Deptid":"",
    "Location":"",
    "Transaction Date":"2014-07-15",
    "Description":"Invoice",
    "Debit":0.0,
    "Credit":13.46,
    "Invoice Nbr":"168243299"
    }]
```

I am using json simple jar to parse the json. my code is:

```
public String appendData(String str) throws IOException, ParseException{
        System.out.println("========Inside appendData======"+str);
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(new StringReader(str));
        double debit = (double) Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.get("Debit").toString());
}
```

Above code works fine, If i send single lock of data and without [ and ] bracket. Above json is a valid json according to [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Question:

1) How do I parse above json having multiple data?

Comment: you parse it into an array or collection of objects

Comment: What do you need to extract from JSON?

Comment: I need to extract all input data from json and update to my file with manipulation. i.e. my business requirement

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax -- it only takes 5-10 minutes.  The outer `[]` indicates a JSON "array", yet you're apparently trying to parse it as an "object".  If you understood the syntax you wouldn't make this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like below for your scenario, if you want to use json-simple:

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                Object obj =  jsonParser.parse(new StringReader(str));
            if (obj instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj;
                 System.out.println(jo.get("Debit").toString());
            } else {
                JSONArray ja = (JSONArray) obj;
                for(int i=0;i<ja.size();i++){
                    JSONObject   jsonObject = (JSONObject)ja.get(i);
                    System.out.println(jsonObject.get("Debit").toString());
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [GSON library](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) is very easy for this kind of tasks

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples

You'll see that to process your array instead of JSONObject you need to us JSONArray. The link has a full example.

I typically use Jackson for my JSON parsing, it is pretty good.